# runtime error '1004': method range of object _worksheet failed EPM BPC VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using pretty basic VBA, but am trying to fix someone else's code after a SP upgrade we just had on SAP\BPC, the EPM add-in.
Please find the code below:

Error Section:

```
For Each CurCell In Input_Sheet.Range(Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN"), Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Offset(Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 0))
```

Code:

```
Private Function AFTER_REFRESH()
    ' Apply the in-cell drop-downs (validations) for the spreads

    Dim CurCell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    UnProtect_Sheet

    For Each CurCell In Input_Sheet.Range(Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN"), Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Offset(Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 0))
        If Not CurCell.Font.Bold Then
            With CurCell.Validation ' apply validation (drop-down) to spread column
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=SPREAD_METHODS"
                .InCellDropdown = True
            End With

        End If
    Next


    If LockWorkbook Then
        Protect_Sheet
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Thank you and kind regards for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G), break your `Input_Sheet.Range(Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN"), Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Offset(Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 0))` line into its components, and see where the error occurs.

Do

```
?Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Address
```

and then

```
?Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

and then

```
Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Offset(Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 0)
```

One of the above will fail and will put you on track to solve the issue. For example, maybe there's no "SPREAD_COLUMN" range on Input_Sheet; maybe the last used row is large enough to cause the offset to push beyond the 1'048'576 rows limit; maybe Input_Sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN") is a whole column that can't be offset vertically; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to change your code to a Sub rather than Function, as it performs a procedure and doesn't return a value.

Have you declared input_sheet outside of the procedure?

```
Option explicit

Private Sub AFTER_REFRESH()
'Apply the in-cell drop-downs (validations) for the spreads

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

UnProtect_Sheet

If not (Input_Sheet is nothing) then

Dim CurCell As Range

On error resume next
Set CurCell = input_sheet.range("SPREAD_COLUMN")
ON error GOTO 0

If not (curcell is nothing) then

For Each CurCell In Input_sheet.Range(Input_sheet.range("SPREAD_COLUMN"), Input_sheet.Range("SPREAD_COLUMN").Offset(Input_Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 0)

If Not CurCell.Font.Bold Then

With CurCell.Validation ' apply validation (drop-down) to spread column 
.Delete 
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=SPREAD_METHODS"
.InCellDropdown = True
End With

End If
Next cell
Else
Msgbox("Input_Sheet exists, but does not contain the range SPREAD_COLUMN.")
End if

    Else
    Msgbox("Input_Sheet does not exist")
    End if

If LockWorkbook Then 
Protect_Sheet
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating= True

End Function
```